# Is this group the 4-permutation group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

Recently I came along the set of $3\times 3$ matrices defined by taking any three vectors of (-1,-1,-1) or the three standard unit basis vectors as your columns. For example, one might take $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 &-1& -1\\
1 &0 &0 \\
0& 1 &0
\end{array}\right),$$ or the identity. Both are of the sort I am interested in. More specifically, I suspect that there is an isomorphism between this set of matrices and the 4-permutation group, $S_4$. However, I am not sure how to prove this. Help, of course, would be appreciated.

Comment: Find the correspondents of the transpositions.

Comment: In your example you take rows instead of columns. My answer applies more naturally if you actually consider columns. Otherwise your matrices act on row vectors.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** Your group naturally acts on the set $$\left\lbrace\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right),\left(\matrix{0\\1\\0}\right),\left(\matrix{0\\0\\1}\right),\left(\matrix{-1\\-1\\-1}\right)\right\rbrace$$ by permutations, via the usual matrix-vector product.

---

Example: your matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 &1& 0\\
-1 &0 &1 \\
-1& 0 &0
\end{array}\right),$$ is the permutation $$\left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) \to \left(\matrix{-1\\-1\\-1}\right) \to \left(\matrix{0\\0\\1}\right) \to \left(\matrix{0\\1\\0}\right)\to \left(\matrix{1\\0\\0}\right) $$

---

Note also that the usual $3\times 3$ permutation matrices (whose columns are all standard unit basis vectors) correspond to the stabilizer of $\ \left(\matrix{-1\\-1\\-1}\right)$ and form a copy of $S_3$ inside $S_4$.

Comment: It's the set of vertices  of one of the regular tetrahedrons inscribed in the cube $[-1,1]^3$

Comment: That would be nice, but it is not regular. The distance between $(-1,-1,-1)$ and $(1,0,0)$ is $\sqrt6$ whereas the distance between  $(1,0,0)$ and  $(0,1,0)$ is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful answer. Indeed, it is certainly not regular. I came across this by taking all the inward pointing normals of the facets of the tetrahedron defined by the points (0,0,0) and the unit basis vectors. To me, it seems that the group acts naturally on any set of normals of some given simplex.

Comment: @IAnemaet You're welcome. Not sure what you mean by *any* set of normals. A simplex has finitely many normals, so you can always fix one of them (say $n$) by choosing a face ($3$ vertices), and then fix the last vertex in such a way that the other $3$ normals avoid the directions $M\cdot n$ for all $M$ in the group.